# uitableviewcell+sdwebimage looks blury

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I'm experimenting with sdwebimage to download images and app shows downloaded images in my custom cell.

When app is open, and sdwebimage complete its task, images looks like blury: [image]

then I scroll up and release it, it looks like nice as it should be : [image]

Both downloaded images and uiimageview in custom cell are 40x40.
my cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like this, can anybody give 
suggestion to handle this problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"promotionCell";

PromotionCell *cell = (PromotionCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PromotionCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = promotionCell;
    self.promotionCell = nil;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

// Get the event corresponding to the current index path and configure the table view cell.

cell.promotiontitle.text = [[promotionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
cell.promotionstore.text = [[promotionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] store];
// cell.promotionimage => uiimageview
[cell.promotionimage setImageWithURL:[[promotionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mobileimage_low] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that my placeholder image, actually is bigger than downloaded from internet, then I think imageview resize placeholder image to fit their view, then this resizing behaviour still kept after sdwebimage comes. I hope this will help those who are dealed with same problem.